# Cannot resolve class from a different module in Java (Intellij)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, ui-automation

I have structured a UI test automation proposal in the following way:

- (parent module) uiTestAutomation
- (child module) ui-utilities
- (child module) ui-domain
- (child module) ui-tests

I want ui-utilities' classes to be able to be used in ui-domain and ui-tests, and also ui-domain's classes to be able to be used in ui-tests.

Here is how my pom.xml files look like:

**parent pom.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>uiTestAutomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>uiTestAutomation</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>ui-utilities</module>
        <module>ui-tests</module>
        <module>ui-domain</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**ui-utilities pom.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>uiTestAutomation</artifactId>
        <groupId>uiTestAutomation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ui-utilities</artifactId>
    <groupId>ui-utilities</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>../ui-domain</module>
        <module>../ui-tests</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**ui-domain pom.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>uiTestAutomation</artifactId>
        <groupId>uiTestAutomation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ui-domain</artifactId>
    <groupId>ui-domain</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
      <module>../ui-tests</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ui-utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**ui-tests pom.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>uiTestAutomation</artifactId>
        <groupId>uiTestAutomation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ui-tests</artifactId>
    <groupId>ui-tests</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ui-utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ui-domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have the BasePage class in ui-utilities, and I want to create a class called LoginPage in ui-domain which should inherit BasePage. However, I get an error saying:

Cannot resolve symbol BasePage

What am I doing wrong in terms of the dependencies in the pom.xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very unusual `pom.xml` structure with `<modules>` pointing all over the place. Parent `pom.xml` looks correct but you shouldn't be using `<modules>` in children modules unless they have their own children modules.

1. Remove the `<modules>` section from all your children modules and use `<dependencies>` to express relationships between modules.
2. Do not change `<groupId>` in the children modules, it makes no sense. It's best if they inherit this from the `<parent>` and you can simply omit `<groupId>` tag in children modules.

Comment: Thanks, those are valid points. But they didn't really solve the problem. Still cannot access the class from ui-utilities :(

Comment: Fix what I have pointed out and run `mvn clean install` from command line. Then post the entire output in your question.

Comment: After fixing and running mvn clean install, the build was successful for all the modules. However, I am still not able to access the class...

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to create the project from scratch one more time. Turned out that when the submodules are being created from the parent module (right click, add new module), intellij sets the parent module to the child modules automatically as early as the first pop-up where the artifactId, groupId are being defined. The pom files are basically the same and mvn clean install works seamlessly for both the parent and separatw child modules.
Now LoginPage can successfully extend BasePage.